# Oracle 9.i SELECT FROM two table and three record to result one record

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I have the following queries (query 1):

```
SELECT AVG(a.nnilai)*75/100 
FROM trangketmhs a WHERE cthajar='20172018' AND a.csmt='E' AND a.kddos='00084'
```

The Result of Query 1:
[click for preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBLO0.png)

(query 2):

```
    SELECT t.nbobot FROM TRNILAIKINERJA t 
WHERE t.ckddos='00084' AND t.cthajar='20172018' AND t.csmt='E' AND t.ckdnilai='TLT'
```

The Result of Query 2: 
[click for preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDWUQ.png)

(query 3):

```
SELECT p.nbobot FROM TRNILAIKINERJA p 
WHERE p.ckddos='00084' AND p.cthajar='20172018' AND p.csmt='E' AND p.ckdnilai='PKM'
```

The result of Query 3:
[click for preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zz15q.png)

So far, I have run this query:

```
SELECT AVG(a.nnilai)*75/100,
(SELECT t.nbobot FROM TRNILAIKINERJA t WHERE t.ckddos='00084' AND t.cthajar='20172018' AND t.csmt='E' AND t.ckdnilai='TLT'),
(SELECT p.nbobot FROM TRNILAIKINERJA p WHERE p.ckddos='00084' AND p.cthajar='20172018' AND p.csmt='E' AND p.ckdnilai='PKM')
 FROM trangketmhs a WHERE cthajar='20172018' AND a.csmt='E' AND a.kddos='00084'
```

But It's result:

> [ORA-00937: not a single-group group function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqmny.png)

The complete record (*) from the queries:

```
SELECT * 
FROM trangketmhs a 
WHERE cthajar='20172018' 
  AND a.csmt='E' 
  AND a.kddos='00084'
```

[click for preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5Ecz.png)

```
(2) and (3) 

SELECT * 
FROM TRNILAIKINERJA t 
WHERE t.ckddos='00084' 
  AND t.cthajar='20172018' 
  AND t.csmt='E'
```

[click for preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnv56.png)

### My Question

How to make the result of 3 queries become this output:

```
| AVG(a.nnilai)*75/100  | NBOBOT1  | NBOBOT2 |
|-----------------------|----------|---------|
|     2,58818181818182  |     0.6  |     0.4 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpler alternative to my previous answer:

```
SELECT a.the_average,
    ,(SELECT t.nbobot FROM TRNILAIKINERJA t WHERE t.ckddos='00084' AND t.cthajar='20172018' AND t.csmt='E' AND t.ckdnilai='TLT') nbobot1
    ,(SELECT p.nbobot FROM TRNILAIKINERJA p WHERE p.ckddos='00084' AND p.cthajar='20172018' AND p.csmt='E' AND p.ckdnilai='PKM') nbobot2
FROM (
  SELECT AVG(a.nnilai)*75/100 the_average
    FROM trangketmhs a WHERE cthajar='20172018' AND a.csmt='E' AND a.kddos='00084'
) a
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but there seems to be no relation between your query on trangketmhs (=a) and the queries on TRNILAIKINERJA (t and p).

So I think you could do something like this:

```
SELECT a.the_average, t.nbobot1, p.nbobot2 
FROM (SELECT AVG(a.nnilai)*75/100 the_average
  FROM trangketmhs a 
  WHERE a.cthajar='20172018' 
  AND a.csmt='E' 
  AND a.kddos='00084') a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT t.nbobot nbobot1 
  FROM TRNILAIKINERJA t 
  WHERE t.ckddos='00084' 
  AND t.cthajar='20172018' 
  AND t.csmt='E' 
  AND t.ckdnilai='TLT') t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT p.nbobot nbobot2 
  FROM TRNILAIKINERJA p 
  WHERE p.ckddos='00084' 
  AND p.cthajar='20172018' 
  AND p.csmt='E' 
  AND p.ckdnilai='PKM') p
```

Comment: thanks for the answer..but the result is: ORA-00905: missing keyword

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use joining the tables as

```
create table trangketmhs(nnilai float,cthajar varchar2(8),csmt varchar2(1),kddos varchar2(8));
insert into trangketmhs values(4.001818181818186,'20172018','E','00084');
insert into trangketmhs values(2.9              ,'20172018','E','00084');

create table trnilaikinerja( ckddos varchar2(8), cthajar varchar2(8), csmt varchar2(1), ckdnilai varchar2(3));
insert into trnilaikinerjavalues('00084','20172018','E','TLT');
insert into trnilaikinerjavalues('00084','20172018','E','PKM');

select avg(t1.nnilai)*75/100 avg_nnilai,
       max(decode(t2.ckdnilai,'TLT',.6)) nbobot1,
       max(decode(t2.ckdnilai,'TLT',.4)) nbobot2 
  from trangketmhs t1
  join trnilaikinerja t2 
    on t1.cthajar = t2.cthajar
   and t1.csmt = t2.csmt
   and t1.kddos = t2.ckddos;

   AVG_NNILAI      NBOBOT1  NBOBOT2
----------------   -------  --------
2,58818181818182     0,6      0,4
```

Comment: sorry..the result is: ORA-32033: unsupported column aliasing..thanks for the reply

Comment: @YohanesSetiawanJapriadi hm, ok it's not possible to use `mutiple with..as` statement for 9i. So, I converted style to creating table individually.